# addObject in Array like xml structure

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Folks, 
I have a Array similar to oneArray bellow, this file is already ready and functional. I want to mount this array dynamic, like addObject, but how can I add a descs value and into it test values ?

Tks for help.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *oneArray;

 self.oneArray = @[ @{ @"desc": @"desc1",
                     @"descs": @[ @{ @"test": @"test1" },
                                  @{ @"test": @"test2" }
                                ]
                     },
                  @{ @"desc": @"desc2",
                     @"descs": @[    @{ @"test": @"test3" },
                                     @{ @"test": @"test4" },
                                     @{ @"test": @"test5" }
                                     ]
                     }
                  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

NSArray can't have Associative name. If you want to have associative name better use NSDictionary.

Comment: Guys, first Tks for help, the problem is that I cant return the structure like exemple from database and need mount dynamic using if and for, the most dificult to me is put the descs reference ...anyway I want to try your options. Tks

Answer (score 1):

You can use for this purpose  json structure and [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), e.g. file content would be

```
[
    {
        "desc": "desc1", 
        "descs": [
            {
                "test": "test1"
            }, 
            {
                "test": "test2"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "desc": "desc2", 
        "descs": [
            {
                "test": "test3"
            }, 
            {
                "test": "test4"
            }, 
            {
                "test": "test5"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And code:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *contentFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"my.json"];
NSArray *descs = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:contentFile options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: Guys, first Tks for help, the problem is that I cant return the structure like exemple from database and need mount dynamic using if and for, the most dificult to me is put the descs reference ...anyway I want to try your options. Tks